# MongoDB: Allow each user to have their own version of a shared document, keeping the ID

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I have a MongoDB collection of Products that all users can view from a website, but I want to allow each user to edit these products' properties (name, price, etc.) while keeping the original ID.

Essentially each user would have their own version of this product, **while still pointing to the same shared product** everyone else uses. If possible the user would then fetch the Products collection, with the edited products replacing the "default" shared products (users most probably won't edit every product, so I'm trying to avoid just copying the whole collection for every user).

Is something like this doable? How would I structure it?

Example:

```
ORIGINAL PRODUCT
id: abc
name: "Car"
price: 50000

USER 1
id: abc
name: "Some car"
price: 64000

USER 2
id: abc
name: "Red car"
price: 48000

/* These all refer to the same product (same id) */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply store users' modifications in embedded document based on user's id.

```
{
  id: "abc",
  name: "Car",
  price: 50000,
  "modifications" : [
    {
      "user_id" : 1, 
      "name" : "Some car", 
      "price" : 64000.0
    }, 
    {
      "user_id" : 2, 
      "name" : "Red car", 
      "price" : 48000.0
    }
  ]
}
```

When querying, use aggregation pipeline to merge user specific values into global values:

```
var user_id = 1234
db.cars.aggregate([
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $mergeObjects: {
          $let: {
            vars: {
              userModifications: {
                $first: {
                  $filter: {
                    input: "$modifications",
                    as: "modification",
                    cond: { $eq: ["$$modification.user_id", user_id] }
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            in: ["$$ROOT", "$$userModifications"]
          }

        }
      }
    },
  },
  {
    $project: { modifications: 0 }
  }
])
```

Comment: In my original answer I have implemented `modifications` as an object, but it should be rather an array. Now I have fixed it.

Comment: I did try your previous implementation earlier and it seems to work perfectly for what I need. Any reason to use arrays instead?

Comment: @dookie-boy It is typical for MongoDB embedded documents like `modifications` to be an array. With arrays you can for example use `$filter` to filter out a subset of modifications for given user IDs, you can `$unwind` the array, show only specified nested field using `$project` etc. If `modifications` was an object, you could only reference single modification by user ID (which is an object key), but you couldn't work with all modifications in bulk.